# How to host Laravel application on Windows Server 2012 using SQL server database

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to install a laravel application on a Windows Server 2012 and using SQL Server. I have added the following extensions to the ext folder

1. php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
2. php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll

And I have also updated the php.ini with the following

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
```

If I remote into the server and run the application, it runs. However when I try to access the application from the public IP, I get the following error:

could not find driver (SQL: select top 6 * from [BANK_TRANS] order by [TRANSACTION_DATE] desc)

What am I getting wrong?